# Matplotlib axis tickmarker alteration

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that simply imports temperature data, assigns variables and plots 3 lines on the same figure. However, the x-axis values are in milliseconds (undesirable) and I would like to convert them to hours... any idea how to do this? Here is my code:

```
def plot_temp(file_name, name):

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_name, index_col = None)

    w = df['Time']
    x = df['Input 1']
    y = df['Input 2']
    z = df['Input 3']

    figsize(6,4)
    plot(w,x, label = "Top_sensor")
    plot(w,y, label = "Mid_sensor")
    plot(w,z, label = 'Bot_sensor')
    title('Temperature log' + name)
    xlabel('Time(ms)')
    ylabel('Temperature (K)')
    legend()
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data? Preferably on something like http://pastebin.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Converting to Hours

The easiest way of doing this would be to convert the array `w` to hours before plotting it.

Just take

```
w = df['Time']
w /= 3600000 # Convert milliseconds to hours
```

## Changing the initial time

To change the initial time of the xaxis to a certain value (say 12 hours) then you could do:

```
initial_time = 12.0
w += initial_time - min(w)
```

Comment: Would there be a way of converting this to a particular time if i know what the initial time is?

Comment: I've added a quick bit on changing this to a particular time